# how to use jquery in dynamics crm 2011 online?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Did anyone use an jquery for controlling form's attributes

I'm interested in Expanding Textareas in forms of entities in Micrsoft CRM 2011

I found some pretty nice [solution](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas)
by using jquery so as to solve my problem but I'm confused how to use jquery methods in CRM

I understood that I have to create some web resources that contain a jquery libraries

Comment: Styling a form with jQuery isn't supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx

Comment: To add to what James said, from [here](http://tinyurl.com/l3uefop), *The only supported use of jQuery in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 web application is to use the jQuery.ajax method to retrieve data from the REST endpoint. Using jQuery to modify Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 application pages or forms is not supported. You may use jQuery within your own HTML web resource pages.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of setting up the jQuery script file as a web resource.

[jQuery Web Resource in CRM 2011](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-web-resource-in-crm-2011.html)

Be sure when adding script files to your form, the reference to the jQuery file is listed before your custom script file that uses jQuery methods.

[Use A JavaScript Web Resource In Your Form](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/p/use-javascript-web-resource-in-your-form.html)